# Series about children transported into classic stories

Tags: story-identification, books

I have been looking for a series that I read when I was 8 for a while. It is about these two kids who read books and then are transported into the story. I loved them and would be very excited to find them again (it is not *Inkheart* or the *Magic Treehouse* series).

If it helps the books the children read were classics normally I think... There was a pirate one as well.

Comment: Do you have a time frame for when the books might have been written? Where they picture books, short chapter books, or full Novels? If they where picture books, did the pictures have anything special about them (style of artwork, distinguishable characters, etc)?

Comment: With a description this vague it could almost, but not quite, be The Chronicles of Narnia.  We need more details.

Comment: Were they transported into real books (that you or I could read), or books that existed only in-universe?

Comment: onewho: they were not picture books...I think they were just short novels for kids. The two main characters were a boy and girl.

Comment: Kyralessa: no it wasn't the chronicles of narnia (I loved the Narnia series though :)) Adele: they were transported into real books as far as I can remember...

Comment: Could you edit the title so it's more descriptive, please?

Answer (score 3):

Could it be the Edward Eager books? They're not strictly a series, although some of them share the same characters. One of the books fits your description somewhat - [Seven-Day Magic](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0152020780)